# how to return a value from javascript to jsp page without using java beans?

Tags: javascript

i need to return a boolean value frm java script to jsp page....

can someone help me??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a bit more information.  Why don't you post the value to the JSP page as a URL parameter?

Answer (score 0):

To send data from Java Script to Server, [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) would be friend for you.